# Is it possible to import another language with grammar-kit?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, bnf, grammar-kit

I am working on a custom language support plugin for Kivy in PyCharm and I think I will need to import some python expressions into it, since .kv files allow some python code in properties definitions and on_properties callbacks definitions.

Is this necessary? How about possible? And how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

If you need several languages in one file this is possible.
A simplier approach is to make some of your PSI elements implement PsiLanguageInjectionHost interface. This will allow to inject other languages into such elements.

If it's not enough you may consider more complex approach described here:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206765105-Tutorial-Custom-templating-language-plugin